# insert counter in action

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to add my Counter in this python action.

Here  is my code:

```
with open('cocktails.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

x = 1
for row in readCSV:
    print(row[1])

    widget.btn_ckt1.setText(row[1])
    print(settext)

    x=x+1
```

Then I want to insert the counter at btn_ckt'COUNTER'

This should be the result:

```
widget.btn_ckt1.setText(row[1])
widget.btn_ckt2.setText(row[1])
...
```

Comment: does this work? `widget["btn_ckt" + str(x)].setText(row[1])`

Comment: The pythonic way to count in a loop is to use enumerate(): for row_i, row in enumerate(readCSV): It starts counting at 0 though.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    widget["btn_ckt" + str(x)].setText(row[1])
TypeError: 'QMainWindow' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is generate names using the counter and access them on the `widget`:

```
with open('cocktails.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    # Using enumerate is "pythonic"
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        # Gives us btn_ckt1, btn_ckt2 and so on...
        name = "btn_ckt" + str(i + 1)  
        # Get attribute
        obj = getattr(widget, name)

        obj.setText(row[1])
```

Comment: I got this error: for i, row in enumerate(reader):
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Stack overflow indentation. -.- Fixed.